# Multiple content provider, onCreate calling order

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In my android app, I have a `content provider`. App is using an `aar` lib which is also having a `content provider`. I want to make sure lib `content provider` get called first.
Is there any way to ensure calling order of them by android system?

I tried to run them but order is not predicable

Comment: Who would be calling them? And what would you consider to be 'calling a content provider'? And how would one 'run' one?

Comment: i edited.. its being called by android system

Comment: When would it be called? Pretty unclear post. And the problem in the title is nowhere mentioned in your post. Write a clear post please.

Comment: @blackapps do u know when content providers are called by android system? if not, they are first things to be called by system before application oncreate

Comment: Why are you talking about onCreate in the title of your post but not even mention it in your post? I said that before. Write a decent understandable post please.

Comment: "Is there any way to ensure calling order of them by android system?" -- I do not think so, sorry!

Comment: @blackapps calling content provider means calling its onCreate. I guess it was hard for u to understand but others understood and even i got answer .. thank you for help tho :)

Comment: @CommonsWare there is.. we have initOrder attritubute in contentprovider that will ensure calling them in order